# What forms of accidents in today's world could cause a landscape to burn for multiple years?

Tags: humans, fire

Oil and gas are the obvious ones, but I wanted to get more creative

Comment: Oil and gas are obvious, so... Coal?

Comment: Fallout (radioactive hot)

Comment: with fallout, wouldn't there need to be something specific that the heat from radiation is causing to combust?

Comment: Not a "landscape" per se, but the Centralia mine fire has been burning for over 50 years. There are spots in the largely abandoned town where the ground is noticeably hot and smoke vents from the ground. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralia_mine_fire

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tire_fire)

> Tire fires, where tires are stored, dumped, or processed, exist in two
>   forms: as fast-burning events, leading to almost immediate loss of
>   control, and as **slow-burning pyrolysis which can continue for over a
>   decade.**

Tire Fire:
[image: Tire Fire]

Tire fires can last a decade or more and are very difficult to extinguish.

Answer (score 7):

[Peat fires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peat#Peat_fires) can burn for a long time, like [coal fires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coal_seam_fire). Being partly underground, the speed of the fire is reduced.

Answer (score 3):

A few examples of fire that have been burning for year involving gas. A simple fire that hits some gas like the eternal flame in Turkey, it's a burning of leaking methane gas from deep under ground but it had to be lit at some point. So just a normal fire or forest fire ?

[image: eternal flame]

Another is a drilling for oil accident that collapsed because it was on a huge cavern of methane, this was attempted to be burned off in Turkmenistan, the fire has now been burning for 40 years.

[image: Hell pit]